# Methods of namedtuple not listed by dir()

Tags: python

In  [8.3. collections — Container datatypes — Python 3.6.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), it specify 5 methods of `namedtuple`.

```
namedtuple_methods = {'_fields', '_make', '_replace', '_asdict', '_source'}
```

Nevertheless, the methods cannot be acquired by `dir` method

```
from collections import namedtuple
set(dir(namedtuple)) & namedtuple_methods
In [64]: set(dir(namedtuple)) & namedtuple_methods
Out[64]: set()
```

They share no intersection.

Interestingly, a particular `namedtuple` lists the methods

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name, author')
In [70]: set(dir(Book)) & namedtuple_methods
Out[70]: {'_asdict', '_fields', '_make', '_replace', '_source'}
```

What's the mechanism behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, classes are objects. And `namedtuple` is a function that creates classes. So you have to distinguish between:

- the `namedtuple` factory function. This is a function that returns a class, which is also an object.
- a namedtuple class, for example `Book = namedtuple('Book', ['name', 'author'])`
- an instance of a namedtuple class, for example `Book('Brave New World', 'Aldous Huxley')`

All of these are different objects. The `dir()` function tries to find the fields (which may be methods) that you can access on that object. So on a class object it will give you the methods and fields in that class. These methods may be class methods or instance methods, depending on their “descriptors”. In particular, `dir(namedtuple)` will list the fields of any function object.